# Check if hand is tracked

Tags: c#, kinect, openni

I want to track my person if I make a fist or if I have my hand open.
It's appreciate if you can give a sample code in C#?
Thank you very much!

Comment: do you have any code or you just want someone to give you solution ?

Comment: let's be honest, a sultution is prefered, google dont give me a suitable result. Thanks

Comment: This is a Q&A site where you can ask questions if you get stuck. It's neither a "Give me the entire solution" nor a "Do my research". Research the topic try you hands on a solution and when you have a __concrete__ problem ask a question

Answer (score 1):

This demo has a simple classifier for closed and open hand:
[Kinect hand tracking](http://kinecthandtracking.codeplex.com/)

however, this is a difficult task in many scenarios using the Kinect.